# router.use middleware chain not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, express

I've the following middlewares:

**injectParamMiddleware.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  req.params.specialParam = 'specialValue';
  next();
}
```

**logParamMiddleware.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.specialParam);
  next();
}
```

**SCENARIO 1**

```
router.get('/resource/:resourceId', 
           injectParamMiddleware,
           logParamMiddleware,
           ...MoreMiddlewares)
```

**SCENARIO 2**

```
router.use('/resource/:resourceId', injectParamMiddleware, logParamMiddleware);
router.get('/resource/:resourceId', ...MoreMiddlewares);
```

While running SCENARIO 1, I get `specialValue` logged in the console.
While running SCENARIO 2, I get `undefined` logged in the console.

I was expecting SCENARIO 2 to log `specialValue`as well.

Any help is really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I'm using Express 4.14.0 and Node 6.10.3

Comment: I usually use `router.all(...)` instead of `router.use(....)` for order dependent stuff, although I thought `use` still respected order..

Comment: It looks like `req.params` gets reset before each middleware that was added using `router.use()` is called. The same doesn't happen for `app.all()`. Not sure if this is documented behaviour, it's certainly something I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 2 is causing an error 'by design' of express as the router is what creates `params`. It is getting overwritten

You can assign the var to another property in the `app.use` that will pass to the request
such as `req.specialParam = 'specialValue'`

```
app.param('/user/:name', (req, res) => {
  req.specialParam = 'specialValue';

});
```

Other options are to modify the params wit the `.param()` method:

```
app.param('/user/:name', (req, res) => {});
```

or

```
app.route('/user/:name')
 .all((req, res) => { ... console log here })
 .get((req, res) => { ... })
```

Comment: i know params are getting overwritten by express, but on EACH LAYER. What i don't understand is why the params object is modified between each middleware only when using `router.use`